# Use Namespaces in PHP 5.2 If Statement

Tags: php, namespaces

Is it possible to use some sort of check before adding namespaces to a script that might be run on a php 5.2 server?

For example, if you want to use doctrine(which requires 5.3) on a 5.3 server, and fallback to PDO on a 5.2 server.

Example:

```
if($pdo){

  //RETURN a pdo connection

}
else if($doctrine){

   //this will fail even if doctrine is false because namespaces are being used
   $classLoader = new Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine\Common');  
   $classLoader->register();

}
```

This is just an example, I am sure I can get this to work without namespaces, but just wondering if there is anyway to use them within an IF statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could tuck the Doctrine code into a separate PHP file and `require()` it inside the `else if` branch.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

```
$classLoaderName = 'Doctrine\\Common\\ClassLoader';
//this will fail even if doctrine is false because namespaces are being used
$classLoader = new $classLoaderName('Doctrine\Common');  
$classLoader->register();
```

Not tested though.